# KiCad 6 clearance on one side only

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

I read an article in which it is mentioned to keep at least 3xW distance from ground plane. I am working on a PCB in which there are other tracks on left side but ground plane on right side. I want to keep the distance from ground plane (right side only). How we can set one side clearance of a track?

Comment: _”I read an article in which it is mentioned”_ Which article and why? Does your board have mains voltage on it? High voltage? High speed differential signals?

Comment: No high voltage and Yes differential signals. USB and micro SD card signals. I was checking online if there are guidelines for such components routing. I dont have exact link of that article now.

Comment: Then it’s the rules for your differential lines you need to follow for trace width, pitch and clearance to plane. What article did you read?

Comment: I wish I had the link to share. My apologies. I found one similar on google below. Please check point#2 in section 3.2...

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/en562805.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I read it initially if you wondered if 3*width is a rule for all signals. For certain high speed signals, there are limitations as the article you provided show. Is your problem that you can only set one rule for a signal which affects all layers and you want per-layer rules?

Comment: I know how to set clearance rule. The problem is the clearance applies on both sides of track. I want to set clearance on one side of track only.

Comment: I can only think of workarounds, not a procedural solution. If you know where the track will be, can you draw a polygon and mark it as keep-out area for the fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up unique clearances for a single trace if you assign it to it's own net class and assign the needed clearance, but as you say that covers both sides of the trace, and that will only apply when running a new trace.

A special keep out area will literally keep out traces but it will not have it's own unique clearance. As an alternative you might create an additional GND fill zone to one side of the trace, then assign a different clearance properties to that zone. Two over-lapping copper fill zones assigned to the same net name will merge to look like one single zone. In some cases you may need to assign a priority level to a zone so that it over rides parameters of another over-lapping zone. Also don't create an unconnected "island" with the zone since that might be automatically removed unless you set the zone parameters appropriately.  See example below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see no other option i guess. So i am accepting it as an answer.